# How to add clear button in CustomDatePicker control (.NET MAUI)?

Tags: android, ios, datepicker, maui

- I have started learning .NET MAUI technology. And I have noticed that DatePicker control does not have support for null/empty value.
- So, I have created custom control using bindable property. Here is my code:

#### CustomDatePickerControl.cs

using System;
using System.Globalization;
​

```cs
namespace TestApp.Controls
{
    public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
    {
        public string _format = null;
        
        public static readonly BindableProperty CustomDateProperty =
               BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomDate), typeof(DateTime?),
               typeof(CustomDatePicker), DateTime.Now,
               BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnDateChanged);
​
        public DateTime? CustomDate
        {
            get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(CustomDateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CustomDateProperty, value); } 
        }
​
        static void OnDateChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            var control = (CustomDatePicker)bindable;
            var dateFormate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            if (control.CustomDate.HasValue)
            {
                if (control._format != null)
                {
                    control.Format = control._format;
                }
                else
                {
                    control.Format = dateFormate;
                }
                control.Date = control.CustomDate.Value;
                control.Opacity = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                control._format = dateFormate;
​
                //Added character in quotes to escape it, otherwise it will not get display properly. 
                control.Format = string.Format("Selec't' 'Date'");
                control.Opacity = 0.3;
            }
        }
​
        protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
​
            if (propertyName == "Date")
            {
                CustomDate = Date;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Use in MainPage.xaml page

```
 <control:CustomDatePicker x:Name="datePicker" />
```

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```
{
    InitializeComponent();
    datePicker.CustomDate = null;
}
```

- It does work fine in both Android and iOS. Now, I want to add clear action button to my CustomDatePicker control so that if user want to clear selected date they can.
- Does anyone know how I can achieve it in MAUI? I do not know much about Xamarin.Forms or MAUI as I'm new to it. If someone can help me on this it will be really helpful.

#### Expected Output:

[image: Ex 1]

[image: Ex 2]

Comment: I don't understand. Where is that button supposed to be located?

Comment: I have added two images, please check. @ewerspej

Comment: You'll need to customize the control per platform for that. In MAUI, that's usually done with handlers/mappers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0 On Android and iOS, you'll need to add the button separately. I haven't done something like this for the DatePicker, yet, so I can only give some guidance at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to adapt the sample prepared for Xamarin in the address below to Maui for Android and iOS. I tested it on Android and it works. I haven't fully tested it on iOS yet.

source code: https://xamgirl.com/clearable-datepicker-in-xamarin-forms/

Firstly, add a class derived from DatePicker to your project.
//app custom datepicker

```
public partial class NullableDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public event EventHandler<NullableDateChangedEventArgs> NullableDateChanged;
    public NullableDatePicker()
    {
        Format = "d";
        FontSize = 12;
    }
    public string _originalFormat = null;

    public static readonly BindableProperty PlaceHolderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PlaceHolder), typeof(string), typeof(NullableDatePicker), "/ . / . /");

    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PlaceHolderProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(PlaceHolderProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty NullableDateProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NullableDate), typeof(DateTime?), typeof(NullableDatePicker), null, defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, null, (b, o, n) =>
    {
        var self = (NullableDatePicker)b;
        var oldValue = ((DateTime?)o)?.Date;
        var newValue = ((DateTime?)n)?.Date;

        self.UpdateDate();

        if (oldValue?.ToString() != newValue?.ToString())
            self.NullableDateChanged?.Invoke(self, new NullableDateChangedEventArgs((DateTime?)oldValue, (DateTime?)newValue));
    });

    public DateTime? NullableDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime?)GetValue(NullableDateProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NullableDateProperty, value?.Date);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDate()
    {
        if (NullableDate.HasValue)
        {
            if (_originalFormat != null)
            {
                Format = _originalFormat;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Format = PlaceHolder;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();
        if (BindingContext != null)
        {
            _originalFormat = Format;
            UpdateDate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);

        if (propertyName == DateProperty.PropertyName || (propertyName == IsFocusedProperty.PropertyName && !IsFocused && (Date.ToString("d") == DateTime.Now.ToString("d"))))
        {
            AssignValue();
        }

        if (propertyName == NullableDateProperty.PropertyName && NullableDate.HasValue)
        {
            Date = NullableDate.Value;
            if (Date.ToString(_originalFormat) == DateTime.Now.ToString(_originalFormat))
            {
                //this code was done because when date selected is the actual date the"DateProperty" does not raise  
                UpdateDate();
            }
        }
    }

    public void CleanDate()
    {
        NullableDate = null;
        UpdateDate();
    }

    public void AssignValue()
    {
        NullableDate = Date;
        UpdateDate();
    }
}
```

Then, add a renderer for each platform in the Platforms folder as follows.
//renderer for android

```
public partial class NullableDatePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<NullableDatePicker, EditText>
{
    DatePickerDialog _dialog;
    private bool _disposedValue;

    public NullableDatePickerRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NullableDatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SetNativeControl(new EditText(Context));

        if (Control == null || e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        Control.Click += OnPickerClick;
        Control.Text = Element.Date.ToString(Element.Format);
        Control.KeyListener = null;
        Control.FocusChange += OnPickerFocusChange;
        Control.Enabled = Element.IsEnabled;
        Control.SetPadding(10, 0, 0, 5);
        Control.TextSize = 14;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == DatePicker.DateProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == DatePicker.FormatProperty.PropertyName)
            SetDate(Element.Date);
    }

    void OnPickerFocusChange(object sender, FocusChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.HasFocus)
        {
            ShowDatePicker();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Control != null && !_disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                Control.Click -= OnPickerClick;
                Control.FocusChange -= OnPickerFocusChange;

                if (_dialog != null)
                {
                    _dialog.Hide();
                    _dialog.Dispose();
                    _dialog = null;
                }
            }
            _disposedValue = true;
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    void OnPickerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowDatePicker();
    }

    void SetDate(DateTime date)
    {
        Control.Text = date.ToString(Element.Format);
        Element.Date = date.Date;

    }

    private void ShowDatePicker()
    {
        CreateDatePickerDialog(Element.Date.Year, Element.Date.Month - 1, Element.Date.Day);
        _dialog.Show();
    }

    void CreateDatePickerDialog(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        NullableDatePicker view = Element;
        _dialog = new DatePickerDialog(Context, (o, e) =>
        {
            view.Date = e.Date;
            ((IElementController)view).SetValueFromRenderer(VisualElement.IsFocusedProperty, false);
            Control.ClearFocus();

            _dialog = null;
        }, year, month, day);

        _dialog.SetButton("Done", (sender, e) =>
        {
            SetDate(_dialog.DatePicker.DateTime);
            Element.Format = Element._originalFormat;
            Element.AssignValue();
        });
        _dialog.SetButton2("Clear", (sender, e) =>
        {
            Element.CleanDate();
            Control.Text = Element.Format;
        });
    }
}
```

//renderer for ios

```
public partial class NullableDatePickerRenderer : ViewRenderer<NullableDatePicker, UIView>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NullableDatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null && this.Control != null)
        {
            this.AddClearButton();

            //this.Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.Line;
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;

            if (DeviceInfo.Idiom == DeviceIdiom.Tablet)
            {
                //this.Control.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(25);
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddClearButton()
    {
        var originalToolbar = this.Control.InputAccessoryView as UIToolbar;

        if (originalToolbar != null && originalToolbar.Items.Length <= 2)
        {
            var clearButton = new UIBarButtonItem("Clear", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, ((sender, ev) =>
            {
                NullableDatePicker baseDatePicker = this.Element as NullableDatePicker;
                this.Element.Unfocus();
                this.Element.Date = DateTime.Now;
                baseDatePicker.CleanDate();

            }));

            var newItems = new List<UIBarButtonItem>();
            foreach (var item in originalToolbar.Items)
            {
                newItems.Add(item);
            }

            newItems.Insert(0, clearButton);

            originalToolbar.Items = newItems.ToArray();
            originalToolbar.SetNeedsDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, add the handlers in MauiProgram.cs.

```
...
    .ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
#if __ANDROID__
                    handlers.AddHandler(typeof(NullableDatePicker), typeof(MyApp.Platforms.Android.Renderers.NullableDatePickerRenderer));
#elif __IOS__
                    //handlers.AddHandler(typeof(NullableDatePicker), typeof(MyApp.Platforms.iOS.Renderers.NullableDatePickerRenderer));
#elif WINDOWS10_0_17763_0_OR_GREATER
                    //handlers.AddHandler(typeof(NullableTimePicker), typeof(MyApp.Platforms.Windows.Renderers.NullableDatePickerRenderer));
#endif
})
...
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Alternatively you can try this custom nullable date time picker for Maui.
https://github.com/sebarslan/Maui.NullableDateTimePicker

Comment: Hi, I am facing below error, could you help me out....

Comment: The type or namespace name 'NullableDateChangedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: public class NullableDateChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public NullableDateChangedEventArgs(DateTime? oldDate, DateTime? newDate)
        {
            NewDate = newDate;
            OldDate = oldDate;
        }

        public DateTime? NewDate { get; }
        public DateTime? OldDate { get; }
    }